# Use AngularJS Decorator to customise uibAccordion

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-decorator

I have a page where I can't modify HTML. I can only attach angular modules to it.
Page contains uibAccordion, with "close-others" set to "true". I need to somehow set it to "false".

```
<uib-accordion close-others="true">
```

The only way that came to my mind was to use a Decorator, but I don't know how to modify the attribute:

```
angular.module('guide', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .config(['$provide', Decorate]);

function Decorate($provide) {

    $provide.decorator('uibAccordionDirective', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {

        $delegate[0].closeOthers = function(openGroup) {
            var closeOthers = false;

        };

        return $delegate;

    }]);
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to modify the function https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.js:

```
... 
$delegate.closeOthers = function(openGroup) {
    var closeOthers = false;
    // var closeOthers = angular.isDefined($attrs.closeOthers) ?
    //     $scope.$eval($attrs.closeOthers) : accordionConfig.closeOthers;
    if (closeOthers) {  // Obviously you can remove this whole line
       angular.forEach(this.groups, function(group) {
          if (group !== openGroup) {
              group.isOpen = false;
          }
       });
    }
};
return $delegate;
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators#what-are-decorators-

Patch the $Delegate section - it replaces the someFn like you want to replace the closeOthers.

Comment: Still can't get it to work..Do I need to apply decorator to 'uibAccordionDirective'? Is there any way to apply it to UibAccordionController? Since the function is declared there

Comment: You should be able to do that by calling the decorator on the UibAccordionController?